# Change database record's value at a specific date and time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I have a Jobs table with a datetime column 'Expiration' and a string column 'Status'. When the record is created, I set the expiration value to next week date and when that day arrives, I want to change the status value.

I'm using SQLite in a Rails application.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a scheduled task or cron job to run once a day to check for jobs which expire on that given day, and if any jobs are found then update their status.

```
expired_jobs = Job.where('expiration < ?', DateTime.now).where.not(:status => 'Expired')
expired_jobs.update_all(:status => 'Expired') if expired_jobs.present?
```

You may like the [whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever).